# Run ionic Cordova app in ios simulator of MAC from visual studio of windows OS

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Iam Unable to run or build my ionic cordova application in ios simulator of mac from my windows OS using visualstudio2015 where i have installed xcode,nodejs and npm and all in my mac still after rebuild it is showing an error message at rebuild command after I am running my app at vs2015 in windows as

> enoent:no such file or directory, open
>   '/users/xx/.taco_home/node_module/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/nodemodules/taco-remote-multiplexer/tacoremotemultiplexer.js
>   in mac

and in windows

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed
>   with error Hook failed with error code 127:
>   /Users/xx/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/17299/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   - 1   ionic-js-sidemenu-ios2      1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error code 127 but not at the same file and i fix it by deleting the hook directory